# htaccess redirect URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have URLs like:

`http://www.mydomain.co.uk/catalogsearch/result/index/?color=24&dir=asc&enable_googlecheckout=1&length=127&limit=15&order=relevance&price=3%2C10&q=test+product&type=141`

These have been submitted to Google a long time ago and are now old and do not work.

I'd really like these kind of URLs redirected to `www.mydomain.co.uk` so anyone searching on google will be redirected to my main URLs homepage rather than the 404 page.

Is this possible in .htaccess?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using mod_rewrite like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain.com/$1 [R,QSA]
```

That should redirect (the R flag) all requests which are not for http://mydomain.com (the RewriteCond to http://mydomain.com keeping the query string (the QSA flag). This will redirect every hostname as well as requests to the ip address. If you want to redirect just www.mydomain.com use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com`.

For more details see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

To redirect from a url like `http://www.mydomain.com/catalogsearch/lots/of/extra/stuff` to `http://www.mydomain.com`, you can do:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com/catalogsearch/(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://www\.mydomain\.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I'm not really looking for that. I need the condition to match www.mydomain.com/searchresult/* i.e. i need to find the `searchresult` string, ignore everything after it and redirect to `www.mydomain.com`

Comment: You should update your question to make that clear. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I have added that, but iin the browser such as Firefox, it says the redirect will never complete. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.co\.uk/catalogsearch/(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www\.mydomain\.co\.uk/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: Replace `.com` with `.co.uk`!

Comment: Ok, so ignore that comment above. The redirect still isn't working though.

Comment: What's happening instead of what you're expecting?

Comment: Nothing. I go to a URL with `catalogsearch/result/index/blah blah` and I still get a 404 rather than redirecting to the www.mydomain.co.uk/ url.

Comment: I assume you have changed `mydomain.co.uk` to the domain name of your site?

Comment: Yes I have changed it to my actual domain name. I've even tried to replace the second instance with google.co.uk but nothing is redirecting.

Comment: Try placing it above all other rewrite rules, just below `RewriteBase /`

Comment: That hasn't changed anything. The page still does not redirect. I'm struggling to think why this is the case.